# I have three data frames, with the same column names but in different order, I need to create a new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have three data frames, dt1, dt2 and dt3, in this format:

```
column names : Asset A Asset B Asset C ... 
row names : dates
```

```
dt1:
           Asset A      Asset B       Asset C     Asset D 
2019-05-30       0     0.03         0.389               0
2019-05-20       1     0.2301       0.002212389       0.5
2019-05-10       0     0.9          0.65                0   

dt2:
           Asset A      Asset C       Asset B     Asset D 
2019-05-30       0     0.82         0.12389             0
2019-05-20       0     0.03982301   0.9                 0
2019-05-10       0.1   0.1          0                   0 

dt2:
           Asset A      Asset D       Asset C     Asset B 
2019-05-30   0.38293    0           0.1           0.48373
2019-05-20   0.483      0           0.1           0.49333
2019-05-10   0.493      0.82        0             0.7893
```

and the data is comprised of values from 0 to 1, however, although they all contain the same column names, they are in different order.

I need to create a new data frame with the same column and row names, but every data point is equal to (dt1 * 0.5) + (dt2 * 0.25) + (dt3 *0.25)

I'm not sure on how to approach this as I've only worked with merging two data frames.

I've tried doing it by merging one and then the other using mapply[intersect()...] but it doesn't give me an accurate result and

Comment: Best if you provided a small *reproducible* example of `dt1`, `dt2`,... You could use `dput(dt1)`, etc..

Comment: of course let me edit

Comment: This is much better but not completely reproducible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Package**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
```

#### Data

Walways provide a reproducible example of your data like this, you can use `dput` function over a slice of your data.

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(
    #date = c("5/30/2019", "5/20/2019", "5/10/2019"),
    asset_a = c(0, 1, 0),
    asset_b = c(0.03, 0.23, 0.9),
    asset_c = c(0.39, 0, 0.65),
    asset_d = c(0, 0.5, 0)),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c("5/30/2019", "5/20/2019", "5/10/2019"))


df2 <- structure(
  list(#date = c("5/30/2019", "5/20/2019", "5/10/2019"),
       asset_a = c(0, 0, 0.1),
       asset_c = c(0.82, 0.04, 0.1),
       asset_b = c(0.12, 0.9, 0),
       asset_d = c(0, 0, 0)),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c("5/30/2019", "5/20/2019", "5/10/2019"))


df3 <-structure(
  list(
    #date = c("5/30/2019", "5/20/2019", "5/10/2019"),
    asset_a = c(0.38, 0.48, 0.49),
    asset_d = c(0, 0, 0.82),
    asset_c = c(0.1, 0.1, 0),
    asset_b = c(0.48, 0.49, 0.79)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("5/30/2019", "5/20/2019", "5/10/2019"))
```

**Multiply all cols by its pondetation before merge**

```
df1 <- df1 %>% rownames_to_column("date") %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(.*0.5))
df2 <- df2 %>% rownames_to_column("date") %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(.*0.25))
df3 <- df3 %>% rownames_to_column("date") %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(.*0.25))
```

**Bind rows together**

To do this Ill use `dplyr::bind_rows` since this function takes as argument two data frames or a list of data frame and bind rows together no matter the order of the cols

```
full_df <- bind_rows(
  list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3),
  .id = "df")
```

**summarising the data**

```
full_df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)
```

#### Everything in a single pipeline

```
list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3) %>%
  purrr::map2(.x =., .y = c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25), 
       ~.x %>% 
         tibble::rownames_to_column("date") %>%
         dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(. * .y))) %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows() %>%
  dplyr::group_by(date) %>%
  dplyr::summarise_all(sum)
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I will from now use the dput function, however, I'm a bit confused by the last part of your answer where you say you've summarised the data, it either tells me ```Error: Column `date` is unknown```. For now I still have a full_df data frame with 9 rows, how should I proceed to merging by adding the ones with the same row name?

Comment: Ah, now I see that dates are rows names in your df. To make this work you just have to store dates as a variable and not as row id in your df. I already change the code for you.

Comment: @GiovanniPignatelli did you do it?

Comment: sorry I was away for work, it gives me an error in the final step, to put everything in a single pipeline: ```Error: Column `dates` already exists in `.data`.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace```

Comment: I have re posted the question in I hope a clearer way if you want to check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785731/combining-rows-from-3-dataframes-with-same-rownames-in-r

Comment: To make it work you have to create again the tree data frames (**Data section**) an then run the code in **Everything in a single pipeline**. Do it, you will see.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to re-align the columns:

```
c1 <- colnames(dt1)
dt1 * 0.5 + dt2[,c1] * 0.25 + dt3[,c1] * 0.25
```

But this also assumes that rows are in same order (`dt2` has May 31st, whereas the others has May 30th), and that the dates are given as rownames (will not be added).

Comment: it was a typo, dates are all the same an in order, my mistake sorry

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please mark it as the correct answer and/or up-vote. With regards to the typo, it emphasises the issues if your data.frames do not completely conforms with each other.

Comment: it gives me ```Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'```

Comment: Sorry, I had used the wrong function. The answer has been updated.

Comment: I think your solution do not work on dataframe but matrices.

Comment: @JohanRosa, you *think* it doesn't work on data.frames? It must definitely works on data.frames.